# simple slide show in JS- buttons are not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a basic page in html that displays a single image.
I also added two buttons Previous and Next. These buttons should allow the user to move forward or backward. Have 6 images in total. When the user reaches the end (or beginning when clicking on the back button) of the slide show, the slide show should not wrap around to the beginning (or end). 
button onclick function for both the cases is not working. Its only getting displayed the first image as what mentioned in the img src attribute.

This is what I have done so far. I put all the images into an array and try to travel the array forward and backward side based on the button click.

```
<body>
<img src="img1.jpg" id="demo" style="width:400px;height:600px"/img>
<br/>
<input type="button" onclick="preImage()" value="Previous                                 
">
<input type="button" onclick = "nextImage()" value="Next                                            
">
<script>
var slider_content = document.getElementById("demo");
var image = ['img1','img2','img3','img4','img5','img6'];

var i = image.length;

function nextImage(){
if(i<image.length){
    i=i+1;
}else{
    i=1;
}
slider_content.innerHTML="<img src="+image[i-1]+".jpg>";
}
function preImage(){
if(i<image.length+1 && i>1){
    i=i-1;
}else{
    i=image.length;
}
  slide_content.innerHTML = "<img src="+image[i-1]+".jpg">
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to backslash the double quotes used to set the `src` attribute and your first `slider_content.innerHTML` doesn't have a double quote to end the attribute value, as for your second `slider_content.innerHTML` you never close the string with a double quote. I suggest you open the browser console to view the errors shown.

Comment: Actually you want to replace `slide_content.innerHTML` with `slide_content.src =image[i-1];`

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper div to your image and change the innerHTML of the div.

```
<div id="demo" style="width:400px;height:600px">
   <img src="img1.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An error needs to be corrected in the preImage function:

`slide_content.innerHTML = "<img src="+image[i-1]+".jpg">`

to

`slider_content.innerHTML = "<img src="+image[i-1]+".jpg>";`

and also what Daniel said.